# Is your source code "pristine"?

Tags: c#

<sub>This was brought about by [this codegolf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63433/19678).</sub>

**Problem**

A program is said to be *pristine* if it is:

1. A working program (No errors).
2. The program will produce errors by removing any contiguous substring of N characters, where `1 <= N < program length`.

My goal is to check if a given C# program's source is pristine or not with the assumption that the given program is already working.

**What I Did**

I generated all possible removal combinations and compiled the resulting string with `CompileAssemblyFromSource`. Compile errors are then checked with `CompilerResults.Errors`.

```
static bool isPristine(string sourceCode)
{
    using (var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } }))
    {
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" });
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

        int length = sourceCode.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < length - i; j++)
            {
                string sourceWithRemoval = sourceCode.Remove(i, j);
                CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceWithRemoval);

                if (results.Errors.Count == 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Still works by removing:");
                    Debug.WriteLine("@{0}@ ", sourceCode.Substring(i, j));
                    Debug.WriteLine("At index {0}.", i);

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Usage**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sourceCode = "class e{static void Main(){System.Console.Write(new char[1\n#if l\n#else\n*5]{'w','o','r','l','d'\n#if o\n#else\n});\n#endif\n}\n#endif\n}";

    Console.WriteLine(isPristine(sourceCode) ? "Pristine" : "Not pristine");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Main Concerns**

- What can I improve (performance, readability)?
- Are there better, faster C# techs that I should have used?

Comment: It never verifies if `sourceCode` is actually a valid program. It will return true for any number of spaces.

Comment: I think "your" definition of pristine is not quite sufficient.   Its still a bag of cack if its been formatted in a way that's unreadable.  All this does is encourages people to produce polished turds.

Comment: @Johnbot Oh. Full disclosure, I did not code according to the problem statement, my intent was to make a verifier for my code-golfed program. This is "bugged" then. Delete? Or am I allowed to change my "goal"?

Comment: @Matt By "pristine", I do not mean C#-standard-pristine. It just so happens that "pristine" was the word chosen for [this codegolf question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63433/19678).

Comment: @helix I think the question is fine as it is. Slightly changing the specification when there aren't any answers is fine. My comment is a comment and not an answer because it's knit picking details when your question makes the context absolutely clear.

Comment: @Johnbot Reworded a bit.

Comment: Shouldn't you run your program after you compile it to somehow compare the outputs of new and original versions? Otherwise IMHO this method makes little sense. You can always remove everything inside `Main` method, for example, and most likely the program will still compile. Does it mean that the original code was not prisitne, even though removig those lines will change the program output drastically?

Comment: @Nikita Yes. As it is defined,  the change in output when removing characters does not matter.

Comment: @helix, what's the point in knowing if the program is pristine or not then? By your definition any program that does something meaningful is not pristine. The only truly pristine program would be a program with empty main method and nothing else.

Comment: @Nikita Sorry, should've made the context really clear. See linked codegolf question that brought about my code.

Answer (score 1):

A few minors really:

1. Standard C# naming convention for methods is `PascalCase`. So should be `IsPristine`.
2. If it's important (or nice) to know which specific sequence is yielding the false result then you should consider returning that from the method. Something like this:

   ```
   public class PristineResult
   {
       public readonly bool IsPristine;
       public readonly string OffendingSequence;
       public readonly string OffendingIndex;

       public PristineResult(bool isPristine, string offendingSequence = null, int offendingIndex = -1)
       {
           IsPristine = isPristine;
           OffendingSequence = offendingSequence;
           OffendingIndex = offendingIndex;
       }
   }

   static PristineResult IsPristine(string sourceCode)
   {
       using (var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } }))
       {
           var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" });
           parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

           int length = sourceCode.Length;

           for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
           {
               for (int j = 1; j < length - i; j++)
               {
                   string sourceWithRemoval = sourceCode.Remove(i, j);
                   CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sourceWithRemoval);

                   if (results.Errors.Count == 0)
                   {
                       return new PristineResult(false, sourceCode.Substring(i, j), i);
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       return new PristineResult(true);
   }
   ```